# invalid conversion from ‘char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive] How to print?? But inside the variable

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, char

```
struct student{
    char name[30]...
};

struct element
{
    struct element *ant;
    struct student databse;
    struct element *prox;
};
```

```
Element *no = *pointer_to_pointer;

cout<< (*no).datbase.name << endl;
```

I printed the name correctly.

```
Element *no = *pointer_to_pointer;

char variable = (*no).datbase.name;
    cout<< variable << endl;
```

Error. Why? How to print? But inside the **`variable`**. Thanks.

Comment: You are casting `(*no).datbase.name` to a char in your last snippet. Use: `char* variable = (*no).datbase.name;`  instead.
If you want to take a char from name, you should index name like this: `char variable = (*no).datbase.name[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `datbase.name` is `char[]`, which means you can not assign it to a `char` variable directly. Use `char *variable` instead:

```cpp
char *variable = (*no).datbase.name;
    cout<< variable << endl;
```

if you want to print just one `char`acter, write:

```
char variable = (*no).datbase.name[0]; //the first character of 'name'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to cast the char array `name` into a single char, this won't work, these types are incompatible.

If you want to use the content of `name`, you should use:

```
const char* variable = (*no).datbase.name;
std::cout << variable << std::endl;
```

If you want to index inside the `name` char array, use `[]` to index it, like this:

```
/* Take first character of name */
char variable = (*no).datbase.name[0];
std::cout << variable << std::endl;
```